# Why is the image not completely rounded-full in NextJS13 with tailwind?

Tags: css, image, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I wanted to round an image with Image Component in NextJS13, but I couldn't

And I styled it with Tailwind, but the full style is not applied

```
   <div className="h-64 w-96 relative">
    <Image
      src={img}
      width={200}
      height={200}
      alt="image"
      className="rounded-full"
    />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
 <Image
  src={img}
  fill
  style={{objectFit:"cover"}}
  alt="image"
  className="rounded-full"
/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).